# Is it proper to ask the HR team by email how to apply a job position they advertise?

Tags: job-search, hiring-process, recruitment, applications

Currently I am interested to a vacancy advertised on a local job portal. However, the advertisement has no information about how should I apply whether it through their official website, certain email or simply through the job portal.

I have a doubt in applying through the job portal as based on my experience, it has the least respond. Especially if this company is big multinational company. Then I googled and found their official HR email.

Is it proper if I sent them an email and ask about how I apply for the vacancy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They posted on the portal to channel all applicants through the portal. These things have tools for managing applications and candidates through selection.

If they wanted you to apply through other means, they would have stated so in the advert.

Answer (score 14):

The job portal is there for a reason, use it. HR will probably tell you the same thing if they even bother answering your email.

Comment: Got to admit I think a most of your answers are over the top in your face but I like this one.  +1

Comment: Blunt, to the point, and everything we love about you +1